# SQLite fails to find existing column in SELECT via JDBC and jOOQ

Tags: java, sql, sqlite, jdbc, jooq

I experience some strange results working with SQLite and JDBC (via JOOQ actually, but this problem can be reproduced by executing the query string manually via JDBC). My database consists of a three tables including a many-to-many and one-to-many relationship. I try to select all values of the 'main' table and join all needed values out of the relationship tables:

```sql
SELECT location.name, 
       world.world, 
       player.player 
FROM   location 
       JOIN world 
         ON location."world-id" = world."world-id" 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (location2player 
                         JOIN player 
                           ON location2player."player-id" = player."player-id") 
                    ON location."location-id" = location2player."location-id"
```

Within JDBC this query fails:

```
java.sql.SQLException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such column: player.player)
```

When I execute the query in an external SQLite editor such as SQLite Manager for Firefox it works as expected.

I work with `sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2` which I cannot change. For reference, the JOOQ query is:

```
create.select(LOCATION.NAME,WORLD.WORLD_,PLAYER.PLAYER_)
            .from(LOCATION
                .join(WORLD)
                    .on(LOCATION.WORLD_ID.eq(WORLD.WORLD_ID)
                )
                .leftOuterJoin(LOCATION2PLAYER
                    .join(PLAYER)
                        .onKey()
                    )
                    .on(LOCATION.LOCATION_ID.eq(LOCATION2PLAYER.LOCATION_ID)
                )
            .fetch()
```

Why fails this query in JDBC and how am I supposed to fix it?

Comment: What SQLite version is the JDBC driver using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I think that you wrote valid ANSI SQL, it may well be that SQLite interprets your statement slightly differently. But you don't really need to nest joins the way you do.  Try this insted:

```sql
SELECT location.name, 
       world.world, 
       player.player 
FROM   location 
       JOIN world 
         ON location."world-id" = world."world-id" 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN location2player 
         ON location."location-id" = location2player."location-id" 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN player 
         ON location2player."player-id" = player."player-id"
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to recreate your issue under sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2 using

```java
sql = 
        "SELECT location.name, " +
            "world.world, " + 
            "player.player " + 
        "FROM " +
            "location " + 
            "JOIN world " + 
                "ON location.\"world-id\" = world.\"world-id\" " + 
            "LEFT OUTER JOIN (location2player " + 
                "JOIN " +
                "player " + 
                    "ON location2player.\"player-id\" = player.\"player-id\") " + 
                "ON location.\"location-id\" = location2player.\"location-id\"";
```

The problem appears to be that the `location2player` and `player` tables are "hidden" inside the parentheses `()` of the sub-join and are unavailable to the initial column list and the final ON clause. The following statement avoids that problem by giving the subquery an alias and using the alias name in those two places:

```java
sql = 
        "SELECT " +
            "location.name, " +
            "world.world, " + 
            "playerlocation.player " + 
        "FROM " +
            "location " + 
            "JOIN " +
            "world " + 
                "ON location.\"world-id\" = world.\"world-id\" " + 
            "LEFT OUTER JOIN " +
            "( " +
                "SELECT location2player.\"location-id\", player.player " +
                "FROM " +
                    "location2player " + 
                    "JOIN " +
                    "player " + 
                        "ON location2player.\"player-id\" = player.\"player-id\"" +
            ") AS playerlocation " + 
                "ON location.\"location-id\" = playerlocation.\"location-id\"";
```

Comment: This works, thanks. Now the question might be how I properly port this back into JOOQ's logic - probably @lukaseder has an idea? Using three separated `.as("playerlocation")` clauses seems a bit ugly.

Comment: @thee: So this really is a SQLite limitation? I would've thought that the original statement was valid ANSI-SQL. I guess, just rewrite your query to [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23967502/521799)

Comment: @LukasEder For what it's worth, the [Mimer SQL-92 Validator](http://developer.mimer.com/validator/parser92/index.tml) says that the original SQL query is "Transitional SQL-92".

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Yes, I thought so. Nesting joins in parentheses is done only rarely, but it should work just like unnested joins. The scope in which tables are defined shouldn't be changed the way it is when a derived table is involved (as in your workaround).